# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index 125 already exists (SQL: create unique index "125" on "roles" ("name", "guard_name")

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Please. how can i fix this. I am testing a Model using laravel PHPunit test, the test attempts to create a record using the Model. Below is the test error stack.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 index 125 already exists (SQL: create unique index "125" on "roles" ("name", "guard_name")

Please what does this really mean and hoe can i fix this?
See my php test file codes, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

// use App\Models\Offer;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DMO\SavingsBond\Models\Offer;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class BondOfferCRUDTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_bond_offer_Model_CRUD()
    {
        $bondOffer_Data = Offer::create([
            'organization_id' => '30734498-bbd6-45c2-9667-0fe45e51705c',
            'status' => 'app',
            'offer_title' => 'Apollos Geofrey',
        ]);

        $this->assertTrue(true);
        // $bondOffer_DB = Offer::find($bondOffer_Data->id);

        // $this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $thread->user);
        // $this->assertEquals($bondOffer_Data['offer_title'], $bondOffer_DB->offer_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that somewhere in your code an index on table “roles” is tried to be created that already exists. Can you please explain why you are using DatabaseMigrations in your test case?

Comment: I suppose the DatabaseMigrations hooks to migrate the database before and after each test.

Comment: Just as you explained above, i carefully reviewed my 'roles' migration file where i have the following;

Comment: Schema::create($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 125);
            $table->string('guard_name', 125);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['name', 'guard_name'], 250);            
            //$table->unique(['name', 'guard_name'], 125);
        });

Comment: just changing  //$table->unique(['name', 'guard_name'], 125); to  $table->unique(['name', 'guard_name'], 250); solved the problem even though i don't know the effect this might trigger subsequently.

Comment: But why do you use the DatabaseMigrations in the test case at all?

Comment: i was able to resolve this bug. the DatabaseMigrations was introduced to help migrate the database and drop all migrations after the test is successfully i guess?

Answer (score 0):

It means that those columns marked as UNIQUE in your DB or in controller you have validation with unique regex like this:

```
Validator::make($data, [           
        'guard_name' => ['required', 'string' , 'unique:users'],
    ]);
```

or like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'guard_name'      => 'required|string|unique:users'
  ]);
```